# Breadboard circuit with PN2222 transistor, LED constantly on

Tags: circuit-design, breadboard, homework

I am trying to build a breadboard circuit for my class assignment using a PN2222 transistor. The LED light is constantly on, without pressing the switch (button). The directions of my assignment suggest that if this occurs it could be due to the orientation of the switch. I am not sure what this means as I have tried to rotate the switch several times with no success. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Electronics SE; Suggestion - Provide a schematic of what you think you are intending to build. Then carefully check the plug board to see if that implements the same circuit. Little or no help will come from here unless you post a schematic as part of your question.

Comment: is this a PNP transistor, or an NPN transistor? what does "P" mean, in PN2222 ?

Comment: Did you check the pin assignments on the PN2222 datasheet? They are not the same as many other NPN transistors such as P2N2222A.

Comment: Do you have an ohmeter to check whether the switch pins are shorted?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf: the P means plastic; it's a TO-92 version of the TO-18 2N2222.

Comment: I suggest that you take a huge step back, remove everything from the breadboard and just use a switch and a resistor in series with an LED and make that work (the LED lights up when the button is pressed). When you have figured that out then you will know how the breadboard connections work and how the switch must be connected. Then move on and add a transistor. Without understanding of how this works you have little chance of making this work even with a simple circuit on a breadboard.

Comment: Please provide a schematic. At the very least, use wires of different colors on your breadboard. Always use black for ground and red for the supply voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to confirm your button orientation (assuming a schematic is not available) is probably with the use of a multimeter - measure the resistance between terminals for both switch states. If the resistance changes from infinite/undefined to very low as you press the button, you've found the NC terminals!